# Which tool (apart from nmap) can I use to scan a range of IPv6 addresses?

Tags: linux, network-scanners, ipv6

When I try to use nmap:

`# nmap -sP -6 FE80::1-234

[...]
Failed to resolve given IPv6 hostname/IP: FE80::1-234.  Note that you can't use '/mask' or '[1-4,7,100-]' style ranges for IPv6.[...]`

What other tool can I use?

Comment: This practical question about using a tool would be more suited to [unix.se] than here. But don't repost the question as is. There's a reason why nmap doesn't support IPv6 ranges: they're rarely useful. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to scan some scope of IPv6 Addresses using existing tool - it is necessary to my research paper.

Comment: @seymourbirkoff - Does this existing tool support IPv6 Addresses?

Comment: Does it work when you ping-scan a single address?

Comment: Since this question was asked, Nmap released version 6.40 in July 2013, which allows CIDR-style IPv6 range scanning.

Answer (score 9):

There was an interesting presentation from Metasploit on this recently (blog post is [here](https://community.rapid7.com/community/metasploit/blog/2012/03/27/identifying-ipv6-security-risks-in-ipv4-networks-tools))

From that there are a number of techniques that nmap can use to identify IPv6 hosts on the local network which could be of use to you

Scanning your local subnet for all IPv6-enabled systems in one shot:

`nmap -6 --script=targets-ipv6-multicast-*`

Port scanning the top 10000 ports on these assets:

`nmap -6 --script=targets-ipv6-multicast-* --script-args=newtargets -PS --top-ports=10000`

Comment: +1 nice catch on the new nmap scripts! The limitation here is that you have to be 'link-local': http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/targets-ipv6-multicast-echo.html

Answer (score 4):

**Using nmap**

Write a short script to generate the IPv6 range you want to scan, then pass that to nmap using `-iL`

```
nmap -Pn -sS -p 80 -6 -iL ipv6.txt
```

**IPv6 Target File**

For the script (if you need help with this part) do a for loop:

```
for i in {1..234}; do echo "FE80::$i" >> ipv6.txt; done
```

The only limit I see with this setup, is that you will have to calculate the appropriate ip range, which might not be simple, depending on the network design.

Comment: Do not forget that IPv6 uses hex numbers: ```for i in {1..234}; do printf "2001:5c0:1400:a::%x\n" $i >> ipv6.txt; done```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [THC-IPv6](http://www.thc.org/thc-ipv6/) as well.

Comment: does thc-ipv6 scan ranges?